# Cannot receive post parameters in php from android?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am sending data from android to php script using json object as follows:

```
            jobj.put("uname", userName);
            jobj.put("password", passWord);
            JSONObject re = JSONParser.doPost(url, jobj);
```

Then the doPost() method is as follows:

```
public static JSONObject doPost(String url, JSONObject c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpEntity entity;
        StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());

        s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        entity = s;
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        try{
            Log.v("Request",""+request);
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
            //Log.v("response",""+response);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.v("Error in response",""+e.getMessage());
            }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            //Log.v("Reader",""+reader.readLine());
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            //Log.v("response",sb.toString());
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.v("response",json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

     // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
```

I have a php script which validates the input as follows:

```
$response = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","manage");
if((isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['password']))){
$empid = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT empid,password FROM master WHERE mm_emp_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($empid)."' and mm_password='".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($result->num_rows != 0){
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "";
    print_r(json_encode($response));
}
else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "The username/password does not match";
    print_r(json_encode($response));
}
}
```

The problem is the isset() does not catch the uname key and I get undefined index for 'uname' and 'password' key. As you can see the json object is converted to string and added as String entity to the request. I cannot figure out what have I been doing wrong that the $_post is not receiving the values.

Please do suggest on what I have been doing so that i can receive the parameters in my php script.

Comment: please try to set content type to your <Head> tag in php as "application/json". i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you are posting data as application/json from android so you can access data in php with:

```
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```